# Retrieve all users asyncronously on .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

I have a .NET MVC application and I want to create a function to get all the users from my database table:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ServicesDbContext>();
        var users = await context.User;

        return users;
    }
```

I tried to make the method `async` which in turn requires an `await`. Unfortunately if I await for the `context.User` to be returned the compiler complains:

> DbSet< User> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter

It sounds like the serviceProvider doesn't allow an asyncronous call to retrieve all the the rows from the database. I understand that retrieving all the stuff in a table doesn't involve complex db filtering like SELECT, WHERE or even JOIN but shouldn't the "get them all" call take some time anyway?

Comment: Also,`GetRequiredService<ServicesDbContext>()` must be an `async` method.

Comment: Have you tried `var users = await context.User.ToListAsync();`, this will required the `System.Data.Entity` namespace

Comment: @AdamT tried and it works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following code?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllAsync()
{
    var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ServicesDbContext>();
    var users = await context.User.ToListAsync();

    return users;
}
```

`.ToListAsync()` is an async method and therefore it can be awaited.

You will need to make sure the following using statement is included:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```